# Is it normal to get the same Goodness of Fit values for a logit model and an LPM model, based on the same data?

Tags: r, glm, lm, confusion-matrix

I am using the Stata dataset ANES.dta with the information about the 2000 presidential election in the USA. I build two models on this dataset - one logit and one LPM. I want to compare the two models with each other using the following Goodness of fit measures - accuracy, sensitivity and specificity of the both models.

I am new to R, I have mainly used STATA so far and that's why I'm wondering if it is normal to get absolutely the same values in confusion matrices for a logit model and a LPM model, based on the same data? Am I doing something wrong?

```
rm(list=ls())

library(foreign)
dat <- read.dta("ANES.dta", convert.factors = FALSE)
dat_clear <- na.omit(dat)
head(dat_clear)

#Logit model
m1_logit <- glm(vote ~ gender + income + pro_choice ,
            data = dat_clear, family = binomial(link = "logit") , 
            na.action = na.omit)
summary(m1_logit)
#LPM
m2_lpm <- lm(vote ~ gender + income + pro_choice,
                  data = dat_clear, na.action = na.omit)
summary(m2_lpm)


#Confusion matrix for logit model
dat_clear$prediction_log <- predict(m1_logit, newdata = dat_clear, type = "response")
dat_clear$vote_pred_log <- as.numeric(dat_clear$prediction_log > .5)
table(observed = dat_clear$vote, predicted = dat_clear$vote_pred_log)


#Confusion matrix for LPM model
dat_clear$prediction_lpm <- predict(m2_lpm, newdata = dat_clear, type = "response")
dat_clear$vote_pred_lpm <- as.numeric(dat_clear$prediction_lpm > .5)
table(observed = dat_clear$vote, predicted = dat_clear$vote_pred_lpm)
```

[This is what the confusion matrices look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g9k7F.png)

Comment: Please edit your question - you shouldn't (ever) post text/code as an image, but always as you already did with text/code around that link.